# Is there any way you can tell MySQL to set value to 0 if value for unsigned column is < 0?

Tags: mysql, update

I have a column in MySQL that is set as `unsigned`; however because I do calculations on this column within MySQL it's possible (though unlikely) that we could try and set this column to a value < `0`.

In this case I just want it to set it to `0` rather than try and set it to a negative value and hence cause an error.

An example would be:

```
UPDATE my_table SET comments=comments-3 WHERE something=123;
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`GREATEST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function (this needs a `CAST()` as well):

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET comments = GREATEST(CAST(comments AS signed)-3, 0) 
WHERE something = 123;
```

or the [`IF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function:

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET comments = IF(comments>3, comments-3, 0) 
WHERE something = 123;
```

or a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET comments = CASE WHEN comments>3 THEN comments-3 ELSE 0 END 
WHERE something = 123;
```

Comment: Hmmm just tried the first option but it doesn't seem to work, getting same `Numeric value out of range` error.